# Изменение цвета текста в webstorm

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains

Подскажите пожалуйста, где можно найти место в настройках вебшторма где можно поменять цвет текста самого приложения, а не кода. Хочу поменять на белый вместо стандартного серого. В дефолтной теме high contrast цвет именно белый, во всех остальных темных темах он какой то серый. Подскажите есть ли вообще такая крутилка или возможно как-то можно поменять этот цвет через тему, тогда какие инструменты существуют для этого?
[image: тема high contrast в которой цвет текста именно белый]

[image: моя тема в которой цвет текста надо поменять]